# How do racial class mechanics actually work?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, races, class, character-levels

For example, I want to play a half-giant. It's a racial class from the D&D 3.5 *Complete Psionic* handbook. I pick it as a race, right?
But I get my racial abilities by taking level. So, when I take a level, I get both racial *and* class level, according to the special leveling table, right?

For example:

- 1 level Half-giant 1 level Cleric
- 2 level Half-giant 1 level Cleric
- 3 level Half-giant 2 level Cleric
- 4 level Half-giant 3 level Cleric
- 5 level Half-giant 4 level Cleric

And last question, may I just use all racial abilities from start, like a LA+1 character?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I get both racial and class level, according to the special leveling table, right?

Right, however you should be aware of which racial abilities you get since you won't get all of them.

> And last question, may I just use all racial abilities from start, like a LA+1 character?

No. Unless you pay the LA as usual (in this case, starting as a level 2 character, level 1 Cleric, you won't get all racial abilities. In the case of the Half-Giant, you only get all the racial abilities at character level 2, whereas you'll be effectively the same as a level 1 class and 1 of Level Adjustment. If your game starts at level 1, the rules say no. You'll start **without** *Powerful build*, *+2 Strength*, *psi-like ability (1/day—stomp)* and the *naturally psionic* abilities.